# Qt dialogs in an OpenGL Context

Tags: qt, opengl, qwidget, qdialog

I was working from this somewhat old example:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq26-openglcanvas.html

The way I understand the example is that QDialog added to the scene with the window flags CustomizeWindowHint and WindowTitle hint should have a title bar like a top level dialog.  When I run the example, however, I have no title bars. :(

I have tried several other flags, as well, but I only see a small QLabel with no title bar.

Code below:

```
QGraphicsView view;

view.setViewport(new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers)));
view.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
view.setScene(new MyGLScene(0));

QDialog *dialog = new QDialog(0, Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint
                              | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint);

dialog->setWindowOpacity(0.8);
dialog->setWindowTitle("Sample");
dialog->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);

dialog->layout()->addWidget(new QLabel("Hello!"));
dialog->layout()->addWidget(new QPushButton("Ok", 0));

view.scene()->addWidget(dialog);
view.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. The `addWidget` method wraps the widget into a `QGraphicsProxyWidget`. For some reasons, the `QGraphicsProxyWidget` seems to ignore the flags or doesn't pass it through.

This is how I fixed it with the use of:

`view.scene()->addWidget(dialog, , dialog->windowFlags());`

your modified code:

```
QGraphicsView view;

view.setViewport(new QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers)));
view.setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
view.setScene(new MyGLScene(0));

QDialog *dialog = new QDialog(0, Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowTitleHint
                              | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint |         Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint);

dialog->setWindowOpacity(0.8);
dialog->setWindowTitle("Sample");
dialog->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);

dialog->layout()->addWidget(new QLabel("Hello!"));
dialog->layout()->addWidget(new QPushButton("Ok", 0));

view.scene()->addWidget(dialog, , dialog->windowFlags());
view.show();
```